# QT Http отправить запрос и обработать

Tags: c++, qt, http

На руках имеется книга QT4 программирование GUI на C++. Читаю и пишу парсер веб страницы. Тут говорится про QHttp, у меня QtCreator не находит данный класс...

Также интересует как можно послать запрос на сайт, получить от него пинг - работает ли он или код ошибки.

А также, как можно скопировать "скелет" сайта в буферный файл для последующих операций над ним.

UPD

Прочитал что использовать QHttp в нашем веке уже не комильфо, и надо использовать QNetworkAccessManager. ( про последнее сомневаюсь )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, в наше время рекомендуют использовать QNetworkAccessManager - он умеет запросы делать, распаралеливать и прочие плюшки.

Самый минимальный пример ([взято здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)):

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

первой строкой создали менеджера (он нужен один на весь проект). Второй строкой соединили сигнал о завершении запроса с слотом (эта строка также обычно одна на весь проект). И третьей собственно делается запрос. В слоте `replyFinished` прилетает ответ, который содержиться в QNetworkReply. У этого объекта есть метод readAll, который позволяет получить ответ, где то так

```
QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
```

также этот объект содержит ссылку на оригинальный запрос, так что можно узнать url, куда был запрос.

В целом, рекомендую начать с изучения этого [примера](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html).

В этой задаче есть ещё одна штука, на которую многие натыкаются и не могут понять - вроде все в include добавили, а qt creator/qmake не видит. Но это просто решается - нужно открыть файл проекта (с расширением pro) и добавить такую строку (где то вверху, там будут подобные строки).

```
QT += network
```

Пинг на сайт можно отправить, но я в этом особого смысла не вижу. Но если сильно-сильно хочется, то конечно можно. На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935103/get-the-ping-from-a-remote-target-with-qt-windows-linux) есть пример.