# Как отправить HTTP запрос?

Tags: c++, http, request

Как мне отправить http запрос к примеру на iplogger.ru так, чтобы затем я увидел в логере новую запись со своим ip адресом? Интересует максимально простое решение.

Comment: Что такое "открыть ссылку скрытно"? - Отправить запрос? Серию запросов? Тогда вы знаете, что делать.

Comment: Да, именно отправить POST запрос, только вот как это сделать?

Comment: видимо не в той половине интернета лазили:)

Comment: Помимо [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html), можно ещё qt, для http запросов использовать: [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661222/23044). Связанный вопрос [How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011339/4279)

Comment: @KoVadim: важно только наличие вопроса дубликата здесь. (я не вижу дубликата. А вы?)

Comment: А я не до конца понимаю Ваш комментарий

Comment: вы видите вопрос-дубликат текущего? Если нет, то не важно где и в каких просторах что есть в интернете.

Comment: Можно отправить так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478054/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-get-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-c/486380#486380

Comment: Можно отправить QT https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516754/qt-http-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: @jfs, посмотрите на то, как выглядел и звучал этот вопрос изначально. KoVadim его послал в правильном направлении.

Comment: @ixSci: если комментарий устарел, его следует удалить.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ это не дубликат. Слова *"чистый С++"*, *"мне бы хотелось самому все это написать"* в том вопросе подразумевают, что нельзя [сторонние библиотеки](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/226557/) использовать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky♦︎ задал связанный вопрос на Мете: [Являются ли вопросы "Как сделать X" и "Как сделать X средствами чистого с++" дубликатами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5817/23044)

Answer (score -6):

Да, это реально очень сложно, так как современные высокоуровневые средства развратили разработчиков и те просто не понимают, что внутри того, что они пишут. Чтобы было просто, можно использовать библиотеки. К примеру, libcurl.

Comment: Воу, придержите коней сарказма ) Ваш ответ будет читать не только ТС, но и другие люди в поисках информации.

Comment: Ради других людей я и добавил в ответ libcurl